# Remove duplicate lines with 1 command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There is any Linux command that deletes duplicates of lines in a file but not the first appearance of the line that is duplicate.

For example, we have a file that has the following lines:

```
Test Line
Another line
Test
4th line
Test
Test Line
```

And I want after I run the command, the lines that should remain in the file are:

```
Test Line
Another Line
Test
4th line
```

Comment: did you try `awk '!a[$0]++' inputfile`  ?

Comment: this command just show the file without the duplicates , but it doesnt really delete the duplicate lines in the original file

Comment: search for in-place replacement using `awk '{...}'  input >input.tmp && mv input.tmp input` construct